# Disable inserted lines in multiline TextBox

Tags: text, textbox, locking, multiline

I have a multiline Textbox for my web page. When user logs in and enters text and press "Save" button, data will be saved. Then, next time when the same user logs in and searches for data, I want him to edit only new text in multiline TextBox, not removing or replacing previously entered text.

Is there any way to make multiline TextBox to lock inserted lines or inserted text and allow to only add text?

Answer (score 0):

If by Textbox you mean "textarea" then it is either disabled or enabled, it can't be both.

You would need to use a client side scripting language such as JavaScript to do what you are after.

You could simply just put the text into HTML and not into the Textarea, that way they can see it but can't change it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip David. I will do that.